# Want a border around image when clicked on and the border removed after clicked on the second time

Tags: javascript, html, css, border

I want to make it so when you click on an image a border shows then when you click on it for the second time it goes away. I've tried many different ways, but first I can't figure out how to get the images to show initially without the borders (only when you click on them the border goes away). From there is when i want to border/disappear when clicked on.

Also, I know you can do in-line css styling in JS, but I don't want to do that. If it's needed though then let me know. I am still learning!

http://jsbin.com/joxuyez/1/edit?html,css,js,output

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="description" content="Practice Refactoring to jQuery">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Practice Refactoring to jQuery</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="refrigerator">
    <div class="oranges">
      <img src="https://whydyoueatthat.files.wordpress.com/2011/12/oranges-vitamin-c-lg.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="apples">
      <img src="http://lymanorchards.com/files/7013/6725/1487/apples.jpg">
    </div>
     <div class="grapes">
      <img src="https://images.homedepot-static.com/productImages/23e05da4-8bdf-4408-8ca0-e9c8c9a780df/svn/van-zyverden-fruit-trees-plants-11425-64_1000.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#refrigerator {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  width: 200px;
  border: 5px solid #333333;
}

#refrigerator img {
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  margin: 30px auto;
}

.oranges {
    border: 5px solid orange;

}      

.apples {
   border: 5px solid red;

} 

.grapes {
   border: 5px solid purple;

}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert("Pick a healthy snack from the refrigerator!");

  });

  $('.oranges').click (function(event) {
  $('.oranges').css("border","none");

    alert("You chose an orange!");    

});

$('.apples').click (function(event) {

    alert("You chose an apple!");       

});

  $('.grapes').click (function(event) {

    alert("You chose grapes!");

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply toggle a class with each click using `toggleClass()`.

Here I updated your CSS a little, and shorten the script, to show how-to.

Why having a border already set, and just change color, you avoid the element from moving, which it otherwise does by default when changing its size.

Stack snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //alert("Pick a healthy snack from the refrigerator!");

});

$('.oranges, .apples, .grapes').click( function(event) {
   $(this).toggleClass("showborder");
   
   if (this.className.includes('showborder')) {
       alert("You selected " + this.className.replace(" showborder","") )
   }
});
```

```css
#refrigerator {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  width: 200px;
  border: 5px solid #333333;
}

#refrigerator img {
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  margin: 30px auto;
}

.oranges, .apples, .grapes {
  border: 5px solid transparent;
}
.oranges.showborder {
  border-color: orange;
}
.apples.showborder {
  border-color: red;
}
.grapes.showborder {
  border-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="refrigerator">
  <div class="oranges">
    <img src="https://whydyoueatthat.files.wordpress.com/2011/12/oranges-vitamin-c-lg.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="apples">
    <img src="http://lymanorchards.com/files/7013/6725/1487/apples.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="grapes">
    <img src="https://images.homedepot-static.com/productImages/23e05da4-8bdf-4408-8ca0-e9c8c9a780df/svn/van-zyverden-fruit-trees-plants-11425-64_1000.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Updated based on a comment.

If you would want to allow only one at the time, you could do something like this

Stack snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //alert("Pick a healthy snack from the refrigerator!");

});

$('.oranges, .apples, .grapes').click(function(event) {

  if ($(this).hasClass("showborder")) {
    $(this).removeClass("showborder");

  } else {
    $(this).parent().find(".showborder").removeClass("showborder");

    $(this).addClass("showborder");

    if (this.className.includes('showborder'))
      alert("You selected " + this.className.replace(" showborder","") )
  }
});
```

```css
#refrigerator {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  width: 200px;
  border: 5px solid #333333;
}

#refrigerator img {
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  margin: 30px auto;
}

.oranges,
.apples,
.grapes {
  border: 5px solid transparent;
}

.oranges.showborder {
  border-color: orange;
}

.apples.showborder {
  border-color: red;
}

.grapes.showborder {
  border-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="refrigerator">
  <div class="oranges">
    <img src="https://whydyoueatthat.files.wordpress.com/2011/12/oranges-vitamin-c-lg.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="apples">
    <img src="http://lymanorchards.com/files/7013/6725/1487/apples.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="grapes">
    <img src="https://images.homedepot-static.com/productImages/23e05da4-8bdf-4408-8ca0-e9c8c9a780df/svn/van-zyverden-fruit-trees-plants-11425-64_1000.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @rainbowpudding You're welcome...and now you can upvote answers too ;)

Comment: Done. If I want to allow to only select one image at a time. For example: I choose Orange then apple, only apple shows as selected (not both). Do I use the .removeClass() method?

Comment: @rainbowpudding Added a 2nd sample to show how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `.toggleClass` with JQuery to handle removing and adding classes. Refer to this JSFiddle I put together. https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/334757/

In JQuery you can make a click handler to target the exact box you're clicking with `$(this)`

Example:

```
var box = $(".box")
box.on("click", function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('border')
})
```

If you need each box to be a different color you can do something like this:

```
.box.border{
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
}

.box1{
  border-color: orange;
}

.box2{
  border-color: red;
}

.box3{
  border-color: blue;
}
```

With this method, you can have a `.border` class whichcontrols the style and width of the border. The different classes such as `.box1` can alter the border color.

```
<div>
  <div class="box box1">box 1</div>
  <div class="box box2">box 2</div>
  <div class="box box3">box 31</div>
</div>
```

Assigned like that. Hope this helps.

Comment: It definitely does, definitely gives me a new way of going about it!

Answer (score 1):

As you are still learning, i have a solution for you in a simple way, though better methods are available but definitely this method will help you to understand whats happening. I have made couple of changes in your CSS and JS file.

It also available at https://jsfiddle.net/9s37v6tu/11/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert("Pick a healthy snack from the refrigerator!");

  });

  $('.oranges').click (function(event) {
  if($('.oranges').hasClass('orange-border'))
    {
       $('.oranges').removeClass('orange-border');
    }
    else
    {
     $('.oranges').addClass('orange-border');
    }
    alert("You chose an orange!");    

});

$('.apples').click (function(event) {

  if($('.apples').hasClass('apple-border'))
    {
       $('.apples').removeClass('apple-border');
    }
    else
    {
     $('.apples').addClass('apple-border');
    }

    alert("You chose an apple!");       

});

  $('.grapes').click (function(event) {
  
    if($('.grapes').hasClass('grape-border'))
    {
       $('.grapes').removeClass('grape-border');
    }
    else
    {
     $('.grapes').addClass('grape-border');
    }

    alert("You chose grapes!");

});
```

```css
#refrigerator {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  width: 200px;
  border: 5px solid #333333;
}

#refrigerator img {
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  margin: 30px auto;
}

.orange-border {
    border: 5px solid orange;

}      

.apple-border {
   border: 5px solid red;

} 

.grape-border {
   border: 5px solid purple;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="description" content="Practice Refactoring to jQuery">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Practice Refactoring to jQuery</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="refrigerator">
    <div class="oranges">
      <img src="https://whydyoueatthat.files.wordpress.com/2011/12/oranges-vitamin-c-lg.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="apples">
      <img src="http://lymanorchards.com/files/7013/6725/1487/apples.jpg">
    </div>
     <div class="grapes">
      <img src="https://images.homedepot-static.com/productImages/23e05da4-8bdf-4408-8ca0-e9c8c9a780df/svn/van-zyverden-fruit-trees-plants-11425-64_1000.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am still learning! Thank you for this, it does help me understand more of what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function(){
       $('.box').click(function(){
           $('.main div').removeClass('border');
           $(this).addClass('border');
           
           var index = $(this).index();
           if(index == 0){alert('YOU CLICKED RED BOX!!!');};
           if(index == 1){alert('YOU CLICKED GREEN BOX!!!');};
           if(index == 2){alert('YOU CLICKED BLUE BOX!!!');};
       });
    });
```

```css
.box{
      display:inline-block;
      width:100px;
      height:100px;
      margin:10px;
}
.red{
       background:red;
}
.green{
       background:green;
}
.blue{
       background:blue;
}

.border{
       border:5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html>
<body>
    <div class="main">
       <div class="box red"></div>
       <div class="box green"></div>
       <div class="box blue"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Appreciate the response!